# Wait for finished async-part before return is fired

Tags: ios, xcode, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

I have problem at trying to prevent my connection-method to quit before the whole connection part has finished.

During the connection progress i'm showing a `progress spinner`.

How can I establish that "return ret" is only called after the whole connection block has finished.

I tried it with `NSCondition` as shown here ([How do I return from a getter of an asynchronous property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15805086/how-do-i-return-from-a-getter-of-an-asynchronous-property)) but with no success....

Her's a part of my code:

```
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:vC.view animated:YES];
hud.labelText = [NSString stringWithFormat: NSLocalizedString(@"login_to_server", @"")];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) {

    //Try to connect

    // If OK
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:vC.view animated:YES];            
    });

    // If NOK
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        [alert show]; // Showing UIAlertView with error message
    });       
});
return ret;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not. To solve your problem you usually have a completion block which will be called once your asynchronous job is done.

Calling your asynchronous method can be done like this:

```
[_activityIndicatorView startAnimating];
[self doSomeAsynchronousWork:^(BOOL success) {
    [_activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
}];
```

Where `doSomeAsynchronousWork:` will look something like this:

```
- (void)doSomeAsynchronousWork:(void (^)(BOOL success))completionBlock {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // do some work and call the completion block once finished
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            completionBlock(YES);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Ok, if that's the only way for doing this i need to rework my code because i wait for the return-value in another method.

Comment: Yeah, and you can do it with a delegate to but the block/gcd-pattern is the one Apple uses in pretty much every new api so it's good practice to use it.

Comment: And why you write "You can not" then?

Comment: Because you can not call a method from the main thread and wait for it to return some value without blocking the main thread. I guessed you wanted non-blocking IO from your use of dispatch_async. If you truly just wanted your method to finish with the network stuff and then return you should just get rid of all those dispatch_async. That however would lead to a horrible UI experience...

Comment: I show an Spinner on the main-thread and in the backround i try to connect to a server. So there is need for dispatch_async and i can't see where there should be a horrible UI experience... The user is notified with a spinner and UIAlertView that communication is taking place...